# The Relationship between PPI and Density-factor in android

Tags: android

According to my basic understanding, if you have a device with higher density(dpi/ppi) you would usually need to use higher density factor (1,1.5,2,3,4) when converting from dp units to px .

The confusion started when I tested this on 2 devices (Galaxy S10+ and Galaxy S20 fe 5g)
according to the specification available on the internet the Galaxy S10+ has higher density at 522 ppi compared to the S20 Fe which has 407 ppi . But when calculating the density factor I found out that for S10+ it is 2.62 compared to the S20 fe which was 3.0 (Check attached screenshots from application introspect)

[image]

[image]

Ref urls for the specifications :

[Galaxy S10+ specifications](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s10+-9535.php)

[Galaxy S20 Fe 5G specifications](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s20_fe_5g-10377.php)

My Question is : is it normal for a device with less ppi to have higher density factor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you shure that S10+ doesn't have some energy-saving mode with lower density/resolution set on some low-level? S10+ have `3040x 1440` screen (aka QHD/1440p), on your screenshot it have `2280 x 1080` (tall "full HD"/1080p). also app is showing lower horizontal and vertical density (below 400) on S10+ than S20 FE

answering question: no, it isn't normal (lower ppi -> higher density), basing on screen display physical params it won't ever happen, but system may add some programmatic logic and scale down some dimens so app may get different rendering params

Comment: Correct. When I checked the display settings there was 3 options for screen resolution (HD+,FHD+,WQHD+) by default it seems the phone was on FHD+ , maybe during setup the choice was offered and the one setup the phone choose the middle Choice . When I have Chosen  WQHD+ I got 3.5 density factor .